# Debug application as a different user in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have an application that works fine when run with administrator privileges. When run by a user it has problems reading from the Event Log. I would like to run the code in the debugger but not with my administrator settings. Is this possible in Visual Studio 2008 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can use [VSCommands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf) to debug with different permissions:
Maybe it's time to upgrade ;)

[image]

Comment: I didn't see Debug as different user options in VS2013.  I tried to follow the links but their site has a lot of 404 errors (as of this posting).  I assume that is a paid feature. I won't down vote but I am tempted to.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the Visual Studio icon and select `Run as...`:

[image]

There's also the [runas.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command you could use to start Visual Studio under a different account.

Comment: @Joshua, yes, that's why I proposed to run Visual Studio under a different account. The `runas` command allows you to specify any user. Didn't you understand my answer?

Comment: @Joshua: Darin wrote absolutly correct information. If you not yet knows RunAs I recommend you to read about it. It can be very helpfull sometimes. Moreover be not so quickly with downvoting of other questions. It's a bad habit.

Comment: Is there's anyway of doing this w/o restarting VS?

Comment: @Nissim, yes, look at [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/eeba26cb-2336-4a80-99f4-ca4167d0758c)

Comment: After looking at the question again (many, many times) I realized my answer would have been correct in the direction I read it as going, but the asker was wanting to go the other direction. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: Old answer, I know but I needed to say it really is helpful! :-D