# Debug while Impersonating Another Domain Account

Tags: c#, sql-server, debugging, impersonation

Is it possible to debug a C# .NET 4 application, run unit tests, etc., using domain user credentials other than my own?  I have several elevated permissions that the users and/or service accounts will not posses, and want to avoid skewing my tests and ultimately suffering from "it works on *my* machine" syndrome.

I specifically want to create a SqlConnection object that uses a domain service account, rather than my own.  I must use a domain account, and not SQL Server account, to allow SQL Server to emit PEXEC calls to other hardware. (Sounds fun, eh?)

I am surprised the option to run debug/release as a different domain user is not already setting in the solution/project Debug properties panel.  It seems like something that would be useful.  Sure, I understand the security risks, but you have to admit that would be very useful in many cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug application as a different user in VS2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434351/debug-application-as-a-different-user-in-vs2008)

Comment: Good eye!  Thanks for redirecting me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434351/debug-application-as-a-different-user-in-vs2008)?  (Using VSCommands addon)

Or this cheap way, from VBForums:

> Create your executable, then using "Run As" execute it under the normal user's credentials. Once it starts, open an instance of VS and attach the debugger to it.

Comment: Good catch.  Normally wouldn't give an upvote to a duplicate link but since you have no rep to close, I'll get you started here.

Comment: woot, thanks! Yeah, it wouldn't even let me leave it as a comment.. I think I need a few more rep for that.